# Postgres - Select from table After If Condition Has Been Satisfied

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm new to the PSQL world. Mainly the `plpgsql` language.
I'm trying to execute the query below; however, I keep receiving the following exception:

> query has no destination for result data

```
do $$
begin
    if 1 > 2 then
        select * from mx.transaction_category_type;
    else
        select * from mx.transaction;
    end if;
end $$;
```

If I use `raise notice '2 is greater than 1'` instead of `select`, this query executes fine.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Do you want your function to *return* the results of the respective query?

Comment: Not creating a function. This should be a simple query. Is it not?

Comment: DO can not return anything. If you want to return something, you must create a function and you have to RETURN a result. Check the the manual for examples